# AttributeError: 'Lines_LineSeries_DataSeries_OHLC_OHLCDateTime_Abst' object has no attribute 'SRNE'

Tags: python

I have a dataframe

```
              timestamp  SRNE   CRSR     GME  ...    ASO     TH     DTE    ATH
0   2021-04-06 00:00:00  7.86  34.66  184.50  ...  31.14  3.230  135.13  51.10
1   2021-04-07 00:00:00  7.58  34.58  177.97  ...  30.78  3.640  135.70  50.47
2   2021-04-08 00:00:00  7.74  34.43  170.26  ...  29.05  3.360  134.95  49.87
3   2021-04-09 00:00:00  7.51  33.52  158.36  ...  30.84  3.125  135.46  50.45
4   2021-04-12 00:00:00  6.94  33.67  141.09  ...  32.29  3.420  135.63  50.80
```

I am creating a back tester and I want to access specific column.
Here is what I tried

```
class TestStrategy(bt.Strategy):

    def log(self, txt, dt=None):
        ''' Logging function fot this strategy'''
        dt = dt or self.datas[0].datetime.date(0)
        print('%s, %s' % (dt.isoformat(), txt))

    def __init__(self):
        # Keep a reference to the "close" line in the data[0] dataseries
        self.dataclose = self.datas[0].SRNE
```

but it gives an error AttributeError: 'Lines_LineSeries_DataSeries_OHLC_OHLCDateTime_Abst' object has no attribute 'SRNE'
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to extend the Datafeed - https://backtrader.com/docu/extending-a-datafeed/

In short, you have to customize the data loader you are using.
If you use bt.feeds.PandasData make sure to first add lines to it.

It could look something like this:

```
class PandasData(bt.feeds.PandasData):
    lines = ('SRNE', 'CRSR', 'GME',  ...    ,'ASO', 'TH', 'DTE', 'ATH')

    params = (('SRNE', -1), ('CRSR', -1), ('GME', -1), ('ASO', -1) etc...)

    datafields = PandasData.datafields + (['SRNE', 'CRSR', 'GME',  ...    ,'ASO', 'TH', 'DTE', 'ATH')])
```

Then you continue with
`data = PandasData(df)` and `cerebro.adddata(data)`

Let me know if that helps. :)